# pm4py Error: cannot import name 'factory' from 'pm4py.algo.discovery.alpha'

Tags: python, mining

I am trying to run the following code:

```
 from pm4py.algo.discovery.alpha import factorial as alpha_miner
 from pm4py.objects.log.importer.xes import factory as xes_importer

 event_log = xes_importer.import_log(os.path.join("tests","input_data","running-example.xes"))
 net, initial_marking, final_marking = alpha_miner.apply(event_log)

 gviz = pn_vis_factory.apply(net, initial_marking, final_marking)
 pn_vis_factory.view(gviz)
```

However, when I run the alpha miner, I get an error message that factory cannot be imported.
What could be the reason or does anyone know a soulution for this?

Many thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
from pm4py.algo.discovery.alpha import algorithm as alpha_miner
```

Answer (score 0):

Find all process discoveries and its information at:
https://pm4py.fit.fraunhofer.de/documentation#discovery

Try this:

```
import os
# Alpha Miner
from pm4py.algo.discovery.alpha import algorithm as alpha_miner
# XES Reader
from pm4py.objects.log.importer.xes import importer as xes_importer
# Visualize
from pm4py.visualization.petri_net import visualizer as pn_visualizer

log = xes_importer.apply(os.path.join("tests","input_data","running-example.xes"))
net, initial_marking, final_marking = alpha_miner.apply(log)
gviz = pn_visualizer.apply(net, initial_marking, final_marking)
pn_visualizer.view(gviz)
```